# Meromorphic function on a Riemann surface with associated holomorphic map

Tags: riemann-surfaces

There is a lemma in Rick Miranda's Book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann surfaces " is the following,

Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on a Riemann surface $X$ , with associated holomorphic map $F:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}_{\infty} $ , show that ,
If $p$ is neither a zero nor a pole of $f$, then  $mult_p(F)=ord_p(f-f(p))$.

What is  holomorphic map associated to a meromorphic function?

Comment: Away from the poles the holomorphic map is $p \mapsto [f(p):1]\in \Bbb{P^1(C)}$. Around a pole it is $p\mapsto [1:1/f(p)]$.

Comment: Okay I understand.   Is this map well defined?

Comment: What do you think?